# How to avoid DOM parsing adding html doctype, <head> and <body> tags?

Tags: php, parsing, dom

```
<?
    $string = '
    Some photos<br>
    <span class="naslov_slike">photo_by_ile_IMG_1676-01</span><br />
    <span class="naslov_slike">photo_by_ile_IMG_1699-01</span><br />
    <span class="naslov_slike">photo_by_ile_IMG_1697-01</span><br />
    <span class="naslov_slike">photo_by_ile_IMG_1695-01</span><br />    
    ';

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($string);
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('span');
    $spans = array();
    foreach($elements as $span) {
        $spans[] = $span;
    }
    foreach($spans as $span) {
        $span->parentNode->removeChild($span);
    }
    echo $dom->saveHTML();


?>
```

I'm using this code to parse strings. When string is returned by this function, it has some added tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>Some photos<br><br><br><br><br></p></body></html>
```

Is there any way to avoid this and to have clean string returned? This input string is just for example, in usage it can be any html string.

Comment: Could you add the input, the output, and the code you're using?  I know you have a link to that last one, but there are a couple of different pieces of code on that particular page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm actually looking for the same solution. I've been using the following method to do this, however the `<p>` around the text node will still be added when you do `loadHTML()`. I don't there's a way to get around that without using another parser, or there's some hidden flag to tell it to not do that.

This code:

```
<?php

function innerHTML($node){
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  foreach ($node->childNodes as $child)
    $doc->appendChild($doc->importNode($child, true));

  return $doc->saveHTML();
}

 $string = '
    Some photos<br>
    <span class="naslov_slike">photo_by_ile_IMG_1676-01</span><br />
    <span class="naslov_slike">photo_by_ile_IMG_1699-01</span><br />
    <span class="naslov_slike">photo_by_ile_IMG_1697-01</span><br />
    <span class="naslov_slike">photo_by_ile_IMG_1695-01</span><br />    
    ';

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->loadHTML($string);
    $elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('span');
    $spans = array();
    foreach($elements as $span) {
        $spans[] = $span;
    }
    foreach($spans as $span) {
        $span->parentNode->removeChild($span);
    }

    echo innerHTML( $dom->documentElement->firstChild );
```

Will output:

```
<p>Some photos<br><br><br><br><br></p>
```

However of course this solution does not keep the markup 100% intact, but it's close.

Comment: This is very close and good solution. I tried to remove <p> and </p> from the end and from beginning of the string using trim function, but it always removes just the first, opening tag, closing tag </p> can't be removed...
Thank you for comment, I hope someone will have solution to remove 'p' tags

Comment: $outputHtml= innerHTML( $dom->documentElement->firstChild );
  if (strpos($html, '<p>') === false) {
    $outputHtml = str_replace(array('<p>', '</p>'), '', $outputHtml);
  }   

  return $outputHtml;

Answer (score 20):

PHP versions since 5.4, when compiled with Libxml 2.6.0 or later, can use the the `options` parameter to [`DomDocument::loadHTML()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php). With it you can do this:

```php
$dom = new \DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string, \LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | \LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
// do stuff
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

We pass two [libxml constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php): `LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD` says not to add a document type definition, and `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` says not to add implied elements like `<html>` and `<body>`.

Answer (score 3):

After using loadHTML, you can do this:

```
# loadHTML causes a !DOCTYPE tag to be added, so remove it:
$dom->removeChild($dom->firstChild);

# it also wraps the code in <html><body></body></html>, so remove that:
$dom->replaceChild($dom->firstChild->firstChild->firstChild, $dom->firstChild);
```

The `!DOCTYPE` tag will be removed, and the first tag inside the `body` tag will replace the `html` tag.

Obviously, this will only work if you're only interested in the first tag inside the `body`, as I was when I encountered this problem. But this example could be adapted to copy everything inside the `body` with a little bit of effort.

Edit: Meh, nevermind. I like meder's solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just use a regex to strip that first bit out:

```
echo preg_replace("/<!DOCTYPE [^>]+>/", "", $dom->saveHTML());
```

Comment: That would probably solve the problem but then using DOM parsing hasn't got point... I used it at first place to avoid regular expressions. Although, I think I'll be forced to use it.
Thanks for your answer

Comment: well, generally you want to avoid using regexes for xml/html because the markup syntax is rather lax and writing a regex which would take it all into consideration is difficult. In this case however, you have a very definite structure with known output, so it's very easy to work with. Don't just blindly follow the "HTML + REGEX == BAD!!" crowd if it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score -1):

From the manual:
http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php

```
$html_fragment = preg_replace('/^<!DOCTYPE.+?>/', '', str_replace( array('<html>', '</html>', '<body>', '</body>'), array('', '', '', ''), $dom->saveHTML()));
```

Works for me.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if either of these will actually work, but you could try using [`DOMImplementation::createDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domimplementation.createdocument.php) when constructing your `DOMDocument` - the third argument is the `DOCTYPE` you wish to use.

Also, instead of `saveHTML()`, you could try [`saveXML()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php)

Comment: geez, sorry for trying to *help*, but I don't have the time to set up tests and recreate the situations described by every question I try to answer. If it's so important to you, why not test out these methods *your*self before downvoting?

Comment: hey kids, it's time for sleep :)))

Comment: dude, if you have time to type an answer you might as well do it in code, in http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://jsbin.com/ and (if and when it works) just copy/paste here...

Comment: Hmm.. seems like I had my cranky pants on back then, hey. Anyway, @Potherca, it's a PHP question, not Javascript.

Comment: @nickf my bad, must have had too many tabs open. Point still stands, URLs should read http://writecodeonline.com/php/ (or my favorite, run https://github.com/Bittarman/BeachPHP on a localhost). :-)