# Get contents of BODY without DOCTYPE, HTML, HEAD and BODY tags

Tags: php

What I am trying to do is include an HTML file within a PHP system (not a problem) but that HTML file also needs to be usable on its own, for various reasons, so I need to know how I can strip the doctype, html, head and body tags in the context of the PHP include, if that's possible.

I'm not particularly good at PHP (doh!) so my searches of the php manual and on the web hasn't made me figure this out. Meaning that any help or reading tips, or both, are much appreciated.

Comment: Use a DOM parser and get the contents of the `body`.

Comment: And your situation means the html file cannot be broken into parts before PHP gets to it? It is a complete document in it's normal state?

Comment: Use the [PHP DOM parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php), load the document, find the body tag, and grab everything inside it. Once you've done that, clear the file and output the contents into the empty file. That will leave you with only what was inside the body tag, nothing else.

Comment: @Jared: yes the html file needs to stay intact on the server, otherwise it wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: You could use a DOM parser, or you could substring on `<body` and `/body>` and then substring again on the first and last occurrences of `>` and `<`. That would leave you with the contents of the `body` tag.

Comment: I edited the title, hopefully that's still accurate. You do mean remove everything that would be found inside those noted tags, right? Only what's IN the `BODY` tag?

Comment: @jeroen and faino: thanks for the reading tip, I'll see what it leads to (other than the sparkly fresh headache I sense is coming on... I did say I'm not especially good at PHP, no? :P)

Comment: @Jared: I only just now saw the change in the title and while I appreciate the effort to make things clearer, something does seem to have gotten lost in the translation. It's not a big deal though.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since the `substr()` method seemed to be too much for some to swallow, here is a DOM parser method:

```
$d = new DOMDocument;
$mock = new DOMDocument;
$d->loadHTML(file_get_contents('/path/to/my.html'));
$body = $d->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
foreach ($body->childNodes as $child){
    $mock->appendChild($mock->importNode($child, true));
}

echo $mock->saveHTML();
```

http://codepad.org/MQVQ3XQP

Anybody wish to see that "other one", see the revisions.

Comment: `...<script>alert('<body>');</script></head></body>...`

Comment: So that's the reason you downvoted me? There was a caveat that in some cases it would not work, depending on the source.

Comment: It's strictly worse than using regexes to parse html. And we all know how SO feels about that. it's more code than using most DOM parsers and it's less robust.

Comment: Thanks Toby. In certain situations, I don't think that is wrong per se, but it was mental laziness on my part not to just look up the DOM parser method.

Comment: And by having the first working answer to use a robust solution, we have made the internet a better place. (Too many times have I seen hacks like this extended in horrible ways to be ok even with a "it'll only be run on this one file ever" justification, cause it never is :P

Comment: I've been in the same position arguing it's bad practice to show a poor approach as an answer when there's a better way. So that's fair. At least I didn't do that *with* a regex too.

Comment: @Jared - your suggestion works (both on my local and webhost servers) exactly as I hoped it would, with the only exception that it trashes special (utf-8) characters. I see that I'll need to read more to fix that problem but it is not a stumbliing block, it can easily be worked around. So, many thanks!

Answer (score 14):

```
$site = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/");

preg_match("/<body[^>]*>(.*?)<\/body>/is", $site, $matches);

echo($matches[1]);
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation of your answer as well, to make the answer more complete

Answer (score 7):

As [miken32](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1255289/miken32) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53111754/530197):

> Hey why not answer a 9 year old question? PHP version 5.4 (released 3
> years after this question was asked) added the `options` parameter to
> `DomDocument::loadHTML()`. With it you can do this:

```php
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);

// do stuff

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

We pass two constants: `LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD` says not to add a document type definition, and `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` says not to add implied elements like `<html>` and `<body>`.

Comment: Elegant and short. You are life savior! :)

Answer (score 5):

Use DOMDocument to keep what you need rather than strip what you don't need (PHP >= 5.3.6)

```
$d = new DOMDocument;
$d->loadHTMLFile($fileLocation);
$body = $d->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
// perform innerhtml on $body by enumerating child nodes 
// and saving them individually
foreach ($body->childNodes as $childNode) {
  echo $d->saveHTML($childNode);
}
```

Comment: @JaredFarrish Look at your codepad again and then look at my code.

Comment: Ok. What am I missing? I use `loadHTML()` instead of the file loader.

Comment: And this gets what I think you're after, unless it's already there and I've munged something in your example on that codepad: http://codepad.org/MQVQ3XQP

Comment: @JaredFarrish I'm passing the `$childNode` as part of the `saveHTML()`

Comment: Right. I didn't realize I had linked to that one. See: http://codepad.org/WfPavGDk *Warning: DOMDocument::saveHTML() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given on line 9.* Plus no output.

Comment: @JaredFarrish It's been introduced since 5.3.6, which has been around for a while.

Comment: Then I suppose mentioning that in the answer is probably worthwhile. Not everybody has that version or higher, unfortunately.

Comment: @JaredFarrish fair enough, but codepad should really upgrade their PHP version; how can anyone demonstrate new language features if they don't keep up? Users will just move to another codepad clone.

Comment: I'm sure there's more to it than just upgrading, seeing the way it's probably setup. There was a project I worked on a while back that required supporting version four; upgrading just isn't in the cards for a variety of reasons. On another note, I don't know if you downvoted my `substr()` "technique" or not, but I've removed it and reversing it would be nice (if it was you). `:)`

Comment: @JaredFarrish I would never :) well, maybe, sometimes, but not this time

Comment: Yeah, I don't downvote very often either. I leave that call to someone else's conviction.

Comment: Boys, thank you for this, is much appreciated. I very much like the approach of saving what's needed rather than stripping out what's not but sadly my webhost is running PHP 5.2.42 which means @Jack's solution won't work at this time. I am saving it though for when the host server is upgraded... (Locally I can test it, of course! :))

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use PHP tidy extension which can fix invalid XHTML structures (in which case DOMDocument load crashes) and also extract body only:

```
$tidy = new tidy();
$htmlBody = $tidy->repairString($html, array(
    'output-xhtml' => true,
    'show-body-only' => true,
), 'utf8');
```

Then load extracted body into DOMDocument:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadHTML($htmlBody);
```

Then traverse, extract, move around XML nodes etc .. and save:

```
$output = $xml->saveXML();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a DOM parser. this is not tested but ought to do what you want

```
$domDoc = new DOMDocument();
$domDoc.loadHTMLFile('/path/to/file');
$body = $domDoc->GetElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
foreach ($body->childNodes as $child){
    echo $child->C14N(); //Note this cannonicalizes the representation of the node, but that's not necessarily a bad thing
}
```

If you want to avoid cannonicalization, you can use [this version](http://codepad.org/MQVQ3XQP) (thanks to @Jared Farrish)

Answer (score 1):

A solution with only one instance of DOMDocument and without loops

```
$d = new DOMDocument();
$d->loadHTML(file_get_contents('/path/to/my.html'));
$body = $d->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
echo $d->saveHTML($body);
```

Answer (score -1):

This may be a solution. I tried it and it works fine.

```js
function parseHTML(string) {
      var   parser = new DOMParser
     , result = parser.parseFromString(string, "text/html");
      return result.firstChild.lastChild.firstChild;
    }
```

Comment: The OP asked for PHP solution, not JS.